# Problem with Darlington Pair Experiment using Two BC547Bs

Tags: transistors, darlington

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyxdO9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In schematic (a), the LED illuminates dimly on holding the 2 probes and gets brighter the harder one squeezes. My understanding of why is this:
The body conducts electricity by the flow of ions and has a very high resistance (ca. 2M ohms - I measured my own) and so the current through it is very low (measured as 3 micro amps). However, the value of beta for a BC547B is at least 200 and so the transistor amplifies the low current by at least this amount which is enough to illuminate the LED, albeit dimly.
If this is so, why then, in schematic (b), when I try to measure the current through the base of Q2, it is so much smaller than that of the base of Q1 in schematic (a) that I cannot measure it using my multimeter i.e. why has the current through the body decreased given that the body's resistance has not changed nor has the voltage of 8.36V?
Another way of putting it is: why is the current Ib of Q1 of schematic (a) different from the current Ib of Q2 of schematic (b) given that the body's resistance hasn't changed, nor has the voltage? I'm new and self-taught so could you please take that into account in your answers - thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: To bring the schematic to life, connect a very high resistance (> 2 MΩ) resistor ("human body") between Vcc and the base. Another hint - replace the 220 Ω R1 with an ammeter with 220 Ω internal resistance to visualize the LED operation. About your astonishment - remember that Ib = Ic/β. In the second circuit, the overall beta is β.β. So ammeters in the bases become unnecessary... if only the transistors are in active mode (Vce > 100 mV).

Comment: In principle, the current should differ very little because the difference between the current-creating voltages in the two circuits is less than one base-emitter voltage drop VF.  Maybe the simulator is doing something wrong because these are very small currents...

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdaqru.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhXmfc.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG5VMy.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening answer. I'm so new that I didn't realise that one can run simulations on circuits so thank you again. I was actually taking real readings with my new (but cheap) multimeter and so that is probably where the discrepancy has arisen. What do you think?

Comment: @J R, And I think so because the measured currents are very small. I am aware that my answer is incomplete - only three schematics without any explanations. But I decided to see if there would be any reaction from you and then finish it.  It would be good to accompany the schematics with explanations. What do you think about this? Do you need it?

Comment: The only querie I have is won't the LED get damaged in real life if the protective resistor is removed and won't this also affect the current?

Comment: @J R, The LED would be damaged if the transistor could supply a high enough collector current. This means that it should be driven with a sufficiently high base current so that it is saturated, i.e.  its collector voltage to be very small, and almost all of the supply voltage to be applied to the LED. The "problem" of the LED is that it behaves like a *dynamic resistor* which reduces its "resistance" when the voltage increases above VF.